# Handling an exception in ProcessRequest in ASP.NET page

Tags: asp.net, web-applications

I placed the following line in web.config, in order to disallow uploads for files bigger than 2 MBs:

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2048" />
```

When I hit the page (which has an FileUpload control) and upload a file larger than 2 MB, the page will throw an exception during ProcessRequest (Callstack below).  I tried overloading ProcessRequest, and I can handle the exception in the catch block.  The problem is, that of course, during ProcessRequest the controls in my page have not been instantiated.

My question is:  Is there a way to handle the exception in a way that I can return a message to the page for the user to see, or somehow, allow the request to go through (deleting the file somehow) so it reaches Page_Load and does normal processing?

Callstack:

```
 at System.Web.UI.Page.HandleError(Exception e)
 at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
 at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
 at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()
 at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestWithNoAssert(HttpContext context)
 at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
 at MyWebsite2.DocDashboard.ProcessRequest(HttpContext req) in MyFile.aspx.cs:line 28
```

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). Also, FYI, this is ASP.NET, not ASP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally was able to solve the problem.  I could not find any information online about it, so I am sharing my solution.  Personally, I don't like the solution all that much but it's the only thing I found to work.  To avoid the crash, override virtual function ProcessRequest, and consume the file from the stream if the file is over the size limit.  Then invoke the base, and it will process the page just fine, file removed.  Here is the code:

```
     public virtual void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        int BUFFER_SIZE = 3 * 1024 * 1024;
        int FILE_SIZE_LIMIT = 2 * 1024 * 1024;
        if (context.Request.Files.Count > 0 &&
                    context.Request.Files[0].ContentLength > FILE_SIZE_LIMIT)
        {
            HttpPostedFile postedFile = context.Request.Files[0];
            Stream workStream = postedFile.InputStream;
            int fileLength = postedFile.ContentLength;
            Byte[] fileBuffer = new Byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
            while (fileLength > 0)
            {
                int bytesToRead = Math.Min(BUFFER_SIZE, fileLength);
                workStream.Read(fileBuffer, 0, bytesToRead);
                fileLength -= bytesToRead;
            }

            workStream.Close();
        }


        base.ProcessRequest(context);
    }
```